# How can I inject DelegatingHandler array for an autorest generated constructor in .net core

Tags: c#, rest, dependency-injection, .net-core, autorest

So, I'm trying to create a rest client using autorest. The code generated has an array of DelegatingHandler in the parameter of the constructor `params DelegatingHandler[] handlers`.

I've never worked with Delegating Handlers before and have no idea on how to inject them. How can I do it?

We are using .net core 1.1 and injecting dependencies using the ConfigureServices method in Startup.cs.

Comment: Do you _need_ to inject them? They are used to proxy `HttpMessageInvoker`s so that you can do stuff like log outgoing requests - so they're just additive, they wrap one another and pass the message along the chain. A `params []` can just be an empty (as in, you don't actually have to pass anything for it to compile).

Comment: I had no idea, thanks! :) I'm not sure on how to add the client service to the services with no parameters, but I'll figure it out now that I now it can be empty.

Answer (score 1):

Really old question, but I happen to know the answer.

1. Create your HttpClient like this:

```
this.httpHandler = CreatePipeline(handlers);
this.httpClient = new HttpClient(httpHandler);
```

2. CreatePipeline looks like this:

```
private static HttpMessageHandler CreatePipeline(IEnumerable<HttpMessageHandler> handlers)
{
    HttpMessageHandler pipeline = handlers.LastOrDefault() ?? DefaultHandlerFactory();
    if (pipeline is DelegatingHandler dHandler && dHandler.InnerHandler == null)
    {
        dHandler.InnerHandler = DefaultHandlerFactory();
        pipeline = dHandler;
    }

    // Wire handlers up in reverse order
    IEnumerable<HttpMessageHandler> reversedHandlers = handlers.Reverse().Skip(1);
    foreach (HttpMessageHandler handler in reversedHandlers)
    {
        dHandler = handler as DelegatingHandler;
        if (dHandler == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException($"bad handler", nameof(handlers));
        }

        dHandler.InnerHandler = pipeline;
        pipeline = dHandler;
    }

    return pipeline;
}
```

You then only have to create a HttpClientHandler (handled by DefaultHandlerFactory), which you can new up easily enough.